# Error 400 from twilio rest API while testing with Postman

Tags: c#, .net, twilio, twilio-api

I was trying to check post method of twilio rest API in postman.Despite of sending the body part raw JSON format it was showing some error 400 code as response. But whenever I was attaching those body details in postman as form format it was working fine. So I am not able to understand why it was not taking that JSON format, if JSON format also working then how should I write that body part for twilio rest API .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Research, try something, add your code & point your problem.

Comment: Could you please add your Post Request including the Json to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you make a request with a body, such as a POST request, you need to send the body as [form encoded parameters, that is as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/request#post).

The Twilio API does not accept JSON bodies.